# kCFURLHFSPathStyle deprecated, what now?

Tags: objective-c, osx-mavericks

I always used this method to create HFS paths,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
path = (NSString *)CFURLCopyFileSystemPath((CFURLRef)url, kCFURLHFSPathStyle);
```

since 10.9 `kCFURLHFSPathStyle` is deprecated. What to use now?

Comment: The use of kCFURLHFSPathStyle is deprecated. The Carbon File Manager, which uses HFS style paths, is deprecated. HFS style paths are unreliable because they can arbitrarily refer to multiple volumes if those volumes have identical volume names. You should instead use kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle wherever possible. ?

Comment: I still want to display HFS paths (compatible issues), Internally I use POSIX but I dont want to take away the option for the users.

Comment: I know this isn't the right forum for product management feedback, but whatever your app is, you can probably safely take away HFS-style path display option. These are only familiar to people who were Mac users before the turn of the century. Unless your application is some niche thing that deals, say, specifically with mounting drives from or emulating Classic OS systems, it may be more confusing than not.